# setText on Buttons not working while on TextView working

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my Firebase Database Structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcZ2o.png)

I'm fairly new to Java and trying to figure out how to solve this.
So I am making a Quiz app till now everything works fine except I cant retrieve data from Firebase RealTime Database.

My layout:
I have a textView to display the question
4 Buttons to display the options that the user can choose from
When the user clicks on a Button it either the Button Color turns to Red or Green depending on the question answer if it was correct or no.
I added one more textView for the timer which is neglected for no

I can only retrieve data for the Question textView but the buttons does not show anything

My Question Class:

```
    package com.example.android.quizapp;
public class Question
{
    public String question,option1,option2,option3,option4,answer;

    public Question(String question,String option1,String option2,String option3,String option4,String answer)
    {
        this.question=question;
        this.option1=option1;
        this.option2=option2;
        this.option3=option3;
        this.option4=option4;
        this.answer=answer;
    }

    public Question()
    {

    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getOption1() {
        return option1;
    }

    public void setOption1(String option1) {
        this.option1 = option1;
    }

    public String getOption2() {
        return option2;
    }

    public void setOption2(String option2) {
        this.option2 = option2;
    }

    public String getOption3() {
        return option3;
    }

    public void setOption3(String option3) {
        this.option3 = option3;
    }

    public String getOption4() {
        return option4;
    }

    public void setOption4(String option4) {
        this.option4 = option4;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
```

My questions java activity class:

```
package com.example.android.quizapp;
import android.app.VoiceInteractor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class questions extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView txtquestions,timer;
    Button OptionA,OptionB,OptionC,OptionD;
    int total=0;
    int correct=0;
    int wrong=0;

    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

        txtquestions=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Questions);
        OptionA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.OptionA);
        OptionB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.OptionB);
        OptionC=(Button)findViewById(R.id.OptionC);
        OptionD=(Button)findViewById(R.id.OptionD);
        timer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

        updateQuestions();
    }

    private void updateQuestions()
    {
        total++;
        if(total>2)
        {
            //open the result activity
            Toast.makeText(questions.this,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions").child(String.valueOf(total));
            reference.addValueEventListener((new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    final Question question=dataSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                    txtquestions.setText(question.getQuestion());
                    OptionA.setText(question.getOption1());
                    OptionB.setText(question.getOption2());
                    OptionC.setText(question.getOption3());
                    OptionD.setText(question.getOption4());

                    OptionA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            if(OptionA.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                            {
                                OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                Handler handler=new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        correct++;
                                        OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
                                        updateQuestions();
                                    }
                                },1500);
                            }
                            else
                                {
                                //answer if wrong...we will find the correct answer and make it green
                                    wrong++;
                                    OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                    if(OptionB.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                    {
                                        OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    }
                                    else if(OptionC.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                    {
                                        OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    }
                                    else if(OptionD.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                    {
                                        OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    }

                                    //Replace all the colors and update the question
                                    Handler handler=new Handler();
                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                            OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                            OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                            OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                            updateQuestions();
                                        }
                                    },1500);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    OptionB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            if(OptionB.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                            {
                                OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                Handler handler=new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        correct++;
                                        OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
                                        updateQuestions();
                                    }
                                },1500);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //answer if wrong...we will find the correct answer and make it green
                                wrong++;
                                OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                if(OptionA.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                {
                                    OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }
                                else if(OptionC.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                {
                                    OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }
                                else if(OptionD.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                {
                                    OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }

                                //Replace all the colors and update the questions
                                Handler handler=new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        updateQuestions();
                                    }
                                },1500);

                            }
                        }
                    });

                    OptionC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            if(OptionC.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                            {
                                OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                Handler handler=new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        correct++;
                                        OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
                                        updateQuestions();
                                    }
                                },1500);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //answer if wrong...we will find the correct answer and make it green
                                wrong++;
                                OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                if(OptionA.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                {
                                    OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }
                                else if(OptionB.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                {
                                    OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }
                                else if(OptionD.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                {
                                    OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }

                                //Replace all the colors and update the questions
                                Handler handler=new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        updateQuestions();
                                    }
                                },1500);

                            }
                        }
                    });

                    OptionD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            if(OptionD.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                            {
                                OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                Handler handler=new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        correct++;
                                        OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
                                        updateQuestions();
                                    }
                                },1500);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //answer if wrong...we will find the correct answer and make it green
                                wrong++;
                                OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                if(OptionA.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                {
                                    OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }
                                else if(OptionB.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                {
                                    OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }
                                else if(OptionC.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))
                                {
                                    OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }

                                //Replace all the colors and update the questions
                                Handler handler=new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        OptionA.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        OptionB.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        OptionC.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        OptionD.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDCC12"));
                                        updateQuestions();
                                    }
                                },1500);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

I only expect for the Buttons to be able to display data from Firebase database and the colors to work correctly because right now they all turn red when pressed

Problem solved I just needed to import a JSON file into my Database instead of creating it from Firebase Database

Answer (score 0):

Don't know this issue but you can simply do get value in string than you can use the string variable for set Text. like that:

```
String A, B, C, D;

A = question.getOption1();
B = question.getOption2();
C = question.getOption3();
D = question.getOption4();

OptionA.setText(A);
OptionB.setText(B);
OptionC.setText(C);
OptionD.setText(D);
```

Just a Suggestion It will be work for you.

Comment: You can check it in debug mode that what the string getting value maybe it getting a null or unknown value

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the options retrieved from database have values?
As you do not provide more details in your code that retrieves data from Database check if your options have values with :

```
Log.i("OptionA value: ", question.getOption1());
```

Check your logcat and tell us what you see.
It seems that the text for you OptionButtons is null. It is normal that all buttons turn red because the answer is compared with null.

Comment: My problem is solved i just imported my JSON file into firebase and now it works